# Redirect_to a different view using the same action as another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using the same action in 2 different views.

How do I redirect_to somewhere if I am in one view but redirect_to somewhere else if I'm in another view?

Thanks

Comment: You mean, after you submit the form, right?

Comment: Yes i have the form in 2 different places :)

Comment: Please post the form part of the differing views

Comment: I think you can for example set `session[:return_to]` dependent on rendered view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get page's url like:

```
url = @template.url_for :back
```

Next, parse url and call right redirect.

Also, You can send page's name to action as an argument, and use

```
params[:page]
```